# Free softwares for editing

Tags: photo-editing

Are there any free software packages like Photoshop that can be used to edit and add effects to photos? I want to create a professional look to my photos.

Comment: By definition free is not the same as professional... you get what you pay for

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here, and in any case "professional look" is much too broad to have a useful answer.

Comment: Clara, you're right that free is not the same as professional, but "you get what you pay for" is a vast oversimplification, especially when it comes to software.

Comment: A search would have turned up http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/what-are-the-alternatives-to-photoshop-is-gimp-a-good-option

Answer (score 1):

Try [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) - it's an open-source alternative to Photoshop (though not as powerful of course).

Comment: Gimp is like photoshop in the same way a [Trabant](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=trabant) is like a [Mclaren](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=mclaren+p1), but then the price difference is kinda similar I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Gimp is very good and you can also try Paint.NET.  It has a very "Photoshopy" feel to it and it is open source.

Comment: Paint.NET isn't open source any more and hasn't been for a few years.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693528/does-paint-net-still-provide-its-source-code

Comment: @JamesSnell I am shocked!  Oh well... but the OP can still download it for free.