# Will Photoshop run on Linux?

Tags: photoshop, software, compatibility, linux

I have installed Photoshop on linux using wine. It's crashing again and again.

Is there any way to use Photoshop on linux?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. Should probably be migrated to either [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com) or possibly [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There are lots of native linux apps that are worth looking at. Sure Phototshop is king, but GIMP is no slouch. The only version I remember that worked pretty well in wine was Photoshop 7.

Comment: @Gmck getting too chatty for comments, but see [What are the key photography-related features from Photoshop that are missing in GIMP?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-are-the-key-photography-related-features-from-photoshop-that-are-missing-in).

Comment: If you are using Linux, GIMP is the best option.

Comment: Looks like there are a lot of photoshop related threads on Unix.SE.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=photoshop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past when attempting to install Photoshop on Linux, I've had little success. In reality there is probably no foolproof solution that will allow Photoshop to run without any problems, though there may be a few more things you can try:

- **Install using [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/)** PlayOnLinux is a program similar to Wine, though is designed primarily to run Windows games on Linux
- **Install using a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) with Windows** If you can get your hands on a Windows install ISO file, you can install Windows within Linux using a virtual machine, with either [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/) (thanks to mattdm in comments) probably being your best options. Once you install Windows with the virtual machine, you can then install Photoshop inside the Windows environment, and boot into it whenever you need to use the program. It is worth noting, mainly depending on your computer, that virtual machines use only a portion of your system's resources, so you need to make sure that the virtual machine has access to enough computing power to run Photoshop.

Alternatively, which may be more than you're asking, you could dual boot Windows alongside Linux, though that is a last resort and probably isn't what your looking for. I reluctantly use Windows, and the ability to use Photoshop is essentially the only reason I don't currently use Linux. If you want to continue trying to install it using Wine, this link may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/530110/how-can-i-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-14-04.

Comment: IME dual boot is simpler to set up than virtualbox, but the latter is more versatile once you've done it.

Comment: Dual boot is also much more performant

Comment: VirtualBox really isn't necessary on modern Linux distributions. The built-in KVM virtualization will work just as well with less hassle.

Comment: Running Linux in a Windows VM works great and would be better if you really want Photoshop and have a recent copy of Windows. I have a Mint 18 VM on a dedicated M.2 SSD and it runs almost as fast as native.