# Are there GIMP plugins that allow one to view and edit EXIF data?

Tags: metadata, gimp

Does anyone know if there is a plugin available for the GIMP that will let you view and edit all the EXIF information associated with an image?

Comment: I couldn't find anything beyond evidence of what appears to be an abandoned project to do that.

Comment: Would be nice to hack the Save-as so the original file name could be buried inside the header. And to put an owner name, read from some config default. So, if I saved DSCN_1234.NEF as Bird.jpg the exif header would (somewhere) preserve DSCN_1234.NEF, so I could look at the jpeg and then find the raw file it was made from. And my jpeg would declare the image as owned by me. This is now required by new European law. Without watermark or header declared ownership, any images found on the web now belong to the public domain.

Comment: I'd like to see a citation on that last claim. I don't follow EU law very closely, but as that would be in direct contradiction to the Berne Convention, _and_ as there has been an increased worldwide trend toward _stronger_ copyright, I'm skeptical.

Comment: mattdm - Sorry to post this as an answer, as I don't have enough rep to add this as a comment, but I think what Colin is referring to is discussed [here](http://www.metafilter.com/127516/Ownership-of-your-digital-works-is-no-longer-automatic-in-the-UK).

Comment: That absolutely does not have the effect claimed. The UK is still a Berne Convention signatory, and copyright is still automatic. Orphan works are a separate issue, and I think the "diligent search" outlined there (because it's defined to actually mean diligent, not cursory) is a reasonable approach. I appreciate the pointer to the discussion, though -- it's interesting stuff. Also, unfortunately, none of this answers the question and is probably all better for [chat].

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but I recommend gThumb (Gnome) or exiv2 (command line).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be honest I'd probably use some photo management software for managing the exif data. It's likely to be more powerful and allow for various batch operations. If you're on Linux, you could try one of the ones listed under [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/321/what-photo-management-software-would-you-recommend-for-linux).

But if you insist, you could try

- the [exif viewer plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/8839) which will let you see the exif data;
- the [save for web plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/33) which will strip exif tags (amongst other operations);

Don't know if that's enough for you, but as I say, I'd use something else for exif manipulation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use the tagging the Picasa provides or use jhead on the command line.
Would have been nice to do it within the GIMP though.

Comment: Good answer but why assume Linux for GIMP? It's cross-platform. Anyway, would love to know a good Windows program for this purpose